# Is it inelegant or a bad practice to use <a href in a view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

In asp.net mvc, mainly in .netcore version, we have some htmlhelpers and taghelpers who help us coding our front end.

I have more affinity with pure html than taghelpers or htmlhelpers.

I'd like to know if it's wrong use some tags in pure html like `<a href>, <label>, <span>` and so on even if the .netcore provides taghelpers or htmlhelpers for that

Comment: I prefer to write pure HTML as much as I can.

Comment: me too, but I don't know if it's common to work this way

Comment: why do you want to do this? use tag helpers

Comment: Using pure html will not only help people who don't understand much about taghelpers, it will also help you to eventually migrate and improve your html since you're not tied to a framework (at least on the templates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not inelegant or bad practice to use html anchor tags instead of tag helpers. I've seen plenty of projects with pure html anchors that were easy to read and maintain.

If you're using named routes, html helpers might save you some refactoring because you can change controllers and actions in your route configuration without having to update your links. But if that's not a big deal to you, don't worry about it.